# simple javascript postmatch not working

Tags: javascript, regex, macros, tags, google-tag-manager

i'm not that familiar with javascript, but i'm trying to do something very simple which works fine on my local, but doesn't seem to work on a 3rd party environment (Google tag manager - macro)...

- I'm trying to match 'hello world' inside the var, 'code'
- then strip out any white space, to include carriage returns, new line breaks, etc.
- as the code currently stands, i notice it's having trouble at this line.... `var result = str[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\"/ig,"");`
- when I debug om my local, the value inside 'str[1]' is a string

here's my code,

```
function (){

var code = '<h2 class="pic">My message</h2>hello world</div>'; 

var patt = /<h2 class="pic">My message<\/h2>(.*?)<\/div>/ig;
var str = patt.exec(code);
var result = str[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\"/ig,"");

return result;

}
```

Am i doing something wrong? is there a fool-proof way to do this that won't break a 3rd party?

Comment: That is what your code does with `result`: https://regex101.com/r/aH4zO7/1. Do you want to remove whitespace and double quotes? Then, see https://regex101.com/r/aH4zO7/2.

Comment: yes, i'd like to remove whitespace, as well as double quotes around the... "value". that's not my main issue though. even if i just do this... var result = str[1], it doesn't seem to work in the 3rd party environment???? maybe it could be the regex that's needed to remove double quotes and carriage returns

Comment: *"Am i doing something wrong?"* - Yes, you are trying to use regular expressions with HTML.

Comment: What happens if you change the last bit to: `return (str !== null) ? str[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\"/ig,"") : false;`?

Comment: Describe *what* you are trying to do, not *how* you are trying to do it. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem (For reference, "I'm trying to match 'hello world' inside the var 'code'" is not what you are trying to do. What is the var `code`? Where does it come from? What does it actually contain? What do you want to do with the text after you have it, and why?)

Comment: hey tenub, using your suggestion.... return (str !== null) ? str[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\"/ig,"") : false; ...it returned false

Comment: i don't get why str would be empty. can you see what i'm doing wrong? to answer Tomalak's question on what am trying to do... everything was in my original post. the variable, 'code' shows the original string, and var 'patt' shows the first regex pattern.... etc., etc.

Comment: Did you forget to enable some option in the 3rd party environment? (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2772452?hl=en)  Also, check to make sure there isn't a special API call for this.

Comment: If everything really was in your original post, then `function () { return "hello world"; }` should be everything you need. That's not what you want? Then you are missing some explanations.

Comment: 'hello world' could be any value. what i need is to regex using (.*?) ...to grab the value between... <h2 class="pic">My message</h2> ...and... </div> . on my local it works fine where str is detected as an object or array, and str[1] gives me the value i need. however, via google tag manager str is null

Comment: No, you most definitely do not need regex for this task, nor should you use it. JavaScript is attached to a very powerful HTML parser (the browser) and you really should write code so that it uses that parser.